# Day of the week field

Tags: php, dayofweek

I have a php database that shows a listing of events...date, end_date event_name and such.

It shows like this on the website:
Date
End Date
Event Time
Event Name
etc...

My client wants to add the day of the week, next to the date field. I can't alter the date field (which is showing as: Month Day). So if the date is August 29 (which is tomorrow), he wants it to display as: Friday, August 29.

Is there a way to go about this, easily? I am not a seasoned programmer.

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code.  If we only know you have 'Month Day', we can't help you get the day of week since the day of week will be different for this date each year.

Comment: If he is using the date() function to output the current string, you could simply change it to date("l, F j") - would output the format you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe you find here your solution: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php)

Comment: Here is the code: <?php echo $row_rsEvents['date']; ?>

I need it to format this way (in conjunction with the end_date field if it is different than the date field):
Friday, August 29 - Saturday, August 30

Comment: @user2930069 what is the value of $row_rsEvents['date']? is it a timestamp? How is it formatted? If you turn it into a timestamp then you can call <? echo date("l, F j", timestamp_here); ?>

Comment: The value of $row_rsEvents['date']? is the start date of the event. This is the field that I need to have show as Month Day: August 29

Comment: Ok...Using this: <?php echo date('l F jS',strtotime($row_rsEvents['date'])); ?> I was able to get it to show the way I want it: Friday, August 29.
I have a end_date field, that if the end_date is greater than the "date" field, I would like it to show that date in the same format.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Be careful, it may be defaulting to "August 29, 2014" using the current year. If you try to access the record next year and it says "August 29, 2015" from the default string to time conversion, the day of the week will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Sjagr...
But can anyone help me with the rest? I need to have it show the "end_date" field, only if the date in that field is greater than the start_date field.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by 'sjagr' the day of the week depends on the month, day of month, and year. Since the year information is missing in your database, and you cannot alter it, you cannot show the day of the week.

Ok, suppose you do know the year. What then? Todd Withers gave the correct hint. This is not as difficult as it may seem, because PHP, or rather your OS, knows a lot about dates. There is this handy PHP function, called date() that takes a 'timestamp' and converts it into readable text, including the day of the week. See:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

A good starting format would be 'l, F j' for the USA, but if you live somewhere else you should change it to something a bit more normal.

Now you need the 'timestamp'. I normally use the strtotime() function for that:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

It's quite flexible and can handle quite a few ways of writing a date. A complete example in code would be:

```
$year  = '2014';  // I use strings, but numbers can also work
$month = '08';    // this is numeric, but names can also work  
$day   = '29';

$timestamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");

echo date('l, F j',$timestamp);
```

Experiment with it, try different formats!

Comment: You guys have been great. What I've ended up with is this:
<?php echo date('l F jS',strtotime($row_rsEvents['date'])); ?>
As you can see, it is displaying the Day of the week, Month and day. It is pulling the date information from a datepicker field. So I think it knows the year, just doesn't display it, correct?

I still though, am trying to figure out how to show the end date of the event, if it is a different date than the start date. I only want it to show it, if when a person submits an event, they enter in the datepicker, a day that is different than the start date.
Thanks!